# haskell tutorial guards example gives a parse error

Tags: haskell

I pasted code from riptutorial . com for Haskell guards. It won't compile.
 This is a super simple sample code. I have triple-checked checked it has spaces not tabs.

there are a few other stack overflow questions with the same compile error, but from more complex code. There has gotta be a simple reason for this!

It works perfectly in the interactive ghci, but I can't figure out how to get ghc to compile an executable. The complete file I'm trying is:

```
main=do
absolute n 
  | n < 0 = -n
  | otherwise = n
```

the full error GHC gives me is "hello.hs:3:3: parse error on input `|'  "

I thought main might need an IO type, so I tried adding `putStrLn "Hello, World!"`, but that gave the same error.

@WillNess  - I'm not questioning your advice that "The order of definitions in a source file does not matter." but.... I'm trying to get this down to the simplest examples. The following compiled OK with ghc:

```
absolute n
 | n<0=(-n)
 | otherwise = n
main=do
let n=absolute 5
print n
```

BUT... moving the definition of absolute to the end, like this:

```
main=do
let n=absolute 5
print n
absolute n
 | n<0=(-n)
 | otherwise = n
```

the GHC compiler crashed with error message absolute.hs:5:2: error: parse error on input `|'

Comment: Please use spaces, ***not* tabs**.

Comment: You need to indent and tormat your code properly, both for Haskell and for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide a [mcve], including the full error message.

Comment: Your code is fine. Be sure to write it in a .hs file, and then load it, rather than entering it line by line in GHCi.

Comment: or, to enter it in GHCi, first type `:{`, press Enter, then paste these lines, press Enter, then type `:}` and press Enter.

Comment: @Idiota please edit the question and include the complete contents of the file you gave to GHC.  The problem isn't in the snippet you posted.

Comment: `main = do` is wrong. try `main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I've got it now. All I had to do was define the function BEFORE the main. Quick question: how do I accept @Will Ness answer? The instructions say "click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." What check mark? I can't see it.

Comment: that's because I broke the rules and posted an answer as a comment instead of posting it as a proper answer. :) it is OK to post your own answer, and later even accept it, to signal that the issue is resolved. you might even get some upvotes! do include the working code though. :) BTW the order of definitions in a source file does *not* matter. the order only matters if you are trying your definitions one by one at the GHCi prompt. even then, put them all between the `:{` and `:}` GHCi commands, and again the order won't matter - for *that* group of definitions.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried adding `putStrLn "Hello, World!"`

That would work if you do it like this:

```
main=do putStrLn "Hello, World!"
absolute n 
  | n < 0 = -n
  | otherwise = n
```

If that's not what you meant, you need to post your actual code.

The problem with just `main = do` is that `do` needs to be followed by a block of code. The "block" can consist of a single `putStrLn`, but it cannot be empty.

The problem with your last attempt is indentation. It needs to be

```
main=do
 let n=absolute 5
 print n
absolute n
 | n<0=(-n)
 | otherwise = n
```

I.e. the body of `main` should be indented more than the `main =` and `absolute n` lines.

Otherwise the whole rest of the file is taken to be part of the `do` block in `main`, and `absolute n | ...` does not make sense as an expression.

(NB: Just because ghc is giving you an error message doesn't mean the compiler crashed. Your code just isn't syntactically valid.)